How to deal with overlapping research?
Two years ago, I started a Master's degree in Natural Language Processing (NLP) in Europe. I suggested my own topic to my supervisor, who was not really an expert in that specific topic (or, at least, to its application to NLP), but they were still excited about the project.
I successfully graduated a few months ago and in September I started a PhD with that same advisor. The PhD is supposed to be a continuation of my Master's work.
However, as you may be aware, the field of NLP is moving incredibly fast, and while my topic was quite niche when I started two years ago, it just recently started to gain traction. I have not published any articles yet: this is not expected during the Master's, and I wanted to publish results from my Master's thesis for a workshop but I wasn't able to (it got accepted but I couldn't go because of unexpected surgery and I'm still kicking myself because of that). However, other people have published a few articles in the last couple of months related to my topic. A team of researchers in particular has interests very close to mine, and I have this weird mixed feeling of excitement and fear. Excitement because I am happy to see peers working on a topic that I like very much. And fear because I realized that I am not "alone" in the field anymore and that there is now some kind of competition (I hate to see things like that but I can't help myself think about it this way).
More precisely, I'm afraid that I won't be able to publish articles because the ideas overlap too much and because I wasn't able to publish first. I'm also afraid that by the time I finish my PhD, other people will have undertaken similar work, probably even with better methodology or results, making my work useless.
I've read a few things online related to that and many were saying that one will always contribute something even if research has already been made because the methodology and results are different. Still, I believe that there is some point where the overlap limit will be crossed and where your work won't necessarily have much impact compared to the first-published work.
I'd like to ask for pieces of advice on how to deal with this situation. I don't want to stop my PhD but I guess I have to make it clear what my next steps should be for the next couple of years.

How to talk about it with my supervisor? As a reminder, they are not an expert for this specific topic. Right now, we worked on the assumption that I should focus on my PhD thesis, but given the recent events in terms of publications related to my domain, and given that I have not yet published, perhaps I should focus on that first to let other academics working on that topic know that I am a part of it too. How to convince my advisor that it should be my top priority?
Should I contact other, new academics working on that topic so that they are aware that I am interested in the topic as well? How should I formulate that exactly? It seems odd to me to just send an email out of the blue to say "Hey! I exist!"
Should I drastically change the methodology of my PhD so as to avoid any potential overlap in the near future? If so, what would be the best way to proceed?


Please ask one question per question

I can think of four strategies for dealing with this. "Hot" areas are a difficult issue, as you note.
The first is to work on something that few others are likely to work on. This is very difficult to judge, of course.
The second is to work on smaller questions, rather than larger ones, where results come quickly. There are no guarantees and you face the additional problem that publishers prefer significant results.
Both of the above are risky.
The third is to work on several, more or less, independent threads simultaneously, so that if you get scooped on one, you don't need to start from scratch. This one can be very intense, but with good note taking might be do-able. Many professionals keep a notebook of potential future work and update it as thoughts occur. Some people Actually prefer to work this way.
The last is to enter into collaborations with people likely to have similar interests so that you get joint publications rather than being closed out. This is easier to do for an established academic, of course, harder for a doctoral student. And, the advisor can have a say about whether this is appropriate for you. In many areas of CS, conference attendance is a good way to find such people. Talk to a lot of people between sessions and explore common interest.
The orthogonal solution is to work on something else, that isn't so hot and that doesn't have so much parallel activity. This might be the shorter path to academic success and less frustrating, but not very satisfying for some. If you choose this path, perhaps it should be something more aligned with your advisor's interests and knowledge.
But, in general, as you note, "hot" areas get a lot of parallel activity and whoever crosses the finish line first is likely to get the prize.
One can also question how well "hotness" correlates with "significance" in actuality rather than just appearance. Tough call.
